# I'm unable to upload an Android build into Internal Testing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-console

I've created a cross-platform project, and I'm using **Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1** to attempted to sign my Android bundle (***.aab**) and get it uploaded to the Play Console for internal testing. However after many tries I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my steps I've taken. To begin, **I created a keystore with the follow bat file**:

```
set /p alias=Enter Alias: 

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey -alias %alias% -keyalg RSA -keystore <APP_NAME>.keystore -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

[image]

**And then I've gone through the Archiving process:**

[image]

**But I always end up with the same error:**

[image]

I've also tried using Visual Studio to create an Ad-Hoc Distribution but that also didn't work.

I must be doing something wrong or missing a step entirely.

Comment: The error suggests that you have uploaded an APK or an App Bundle previously. All the artifacts you upload to the Play Console should all be signed with the same keystore. So the error means that you signed the App Bundle with a key that is different than the ones you have uploaded previously.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT how do I clear all previous ones and treat the latest one as if it's the first one ?

Comment: You have to either find that keystore you used before or reset the key by contacting Play Console support team.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT since my so has never been released, I'm guessing another option can be to simply delete the app from the console and stay over too?

Comment: I'm afraid not..You can read it [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en),the last one.

Comment: Is the above information useful to you?

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I'm in the process of doing. Thank you for explaining this error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to contact Google Play Console Support as they will be able to help you by reseting the keystore.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.

Comment: I just chatted with them and it was quick, they will soon reset the key 

Comment: Received an email from support, it states "Make sure to update your keystores in the following locations", such as local machine. What does that mean, I have to re-generate a new keystore before my next package upload to the store?

Comment: I would ask them to clarify what they mean. I am not sure myself. When I had a keystore issue, they told me to generate a new one and send them the certificate fingerprint so they could reset it and then I could update my app with the new keystore.